# C: Assigning new item to "next" pointer in linked list fails

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list

I have encountered a bug in the following linked list function and I have no idea what to do. The crazy part (to me) is that my code has been working perfectly up to now, and still does for several calls before hitting the bug.

The goal of this function is to add a new item (PathItem, which contains a BinaryItem) to the end of a linked list of PathItems. My function is as follows

```
void addPathItemAtEnd(struct PathItem * pathItem, struct BinaryItem * binaryItem) {
    if (pathItem == NULL) {
        pathItem = malloc(sizeof(struct PathItem));
        pathItem->binaryItem = binaryItem;
        pathItem->next = NULL;
    } else {
        while (pathItem->next != NULL) {
            pathItem = pathItem->next;
        }
        struct PathItem * newPathItem = malloc(sizeof(struct PathItem));
        newPathItem->binaryItem = binaryItem;
        newPathItem->next = NULL;
        pathItem->next = newPathItem;        
    }
}
```

with the problematic line being `pathItem->next = newPathItem`. I get the error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in the debugger. Once again, this code has functioned fine before, so I can't understand what is happening now to upset it...

This seems to be an issue with reassigning the pointer variable. Don't know what's wrong.

Any thoughts, suggestions, criticisms. If needed, I can attach more/the rest of my code. Really need your help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that `pathItem` is passed in as a *copy* so that changes to it are not reflected back in the original code. C uses a pass-by-value paradigm (C++ also uses pass by value but it at least has reference types so you don't have to muck about with C's obtuse pointer methods).

I can't see how this *ever* would have worked simply because, if the pointer you pass in as `pathItem` is initially NULL, it *stays* NULL when you return. In other words, the list is always empty.

Probably the easiest fix to that is to change the prototype to:

```
void addPathItemAtEnd (struct PathItem *pPathItem, blah blah blah ...
```

and then, wherever you currently have `pathItem` inside that function, replace it with `(*pPathItem)`.

And, of course, call it with the pointer, changing (something like):

```
addPathItemAtEnd (listStart, newItem);
```

to:

```
addPathItemAtEnd (&listStart, newItem);
```

---

As an aside, robust code would also check the return value from `malloc` and act accordingly. While classwork and little personal projects may be able to get away with assuming no failures, that won't cut it in the real world :-)

Comment: OK, thanks! So then I have a followup question: how can I get pathItem passed in as the original? All my other functions are using this same approach and appear to be working successfully.

Comment: @Arman, you need to pass in a pointer to the pointer so that you can change it. See the update I made to the answer.

Comment: Now I am confused about this pointer-to-pointer business (which I will definitely read up on). First of all, I implemented your suggested solution to the best of my understanding (not that much) and don't quite have it working yet. The other thing is, despite your doubts of my method, it seems to work in at least other circumstances (I will add an example below). Although I admit the NULL issue probably won't work now that I think about it. But see the similar method for BinaryItem I implemented that I have tested and does add the new value to the end of the BinaryItem Linked List.

Comment: `void addBinaryItemAtEnd(struct BinaryItem * binaryItem, _Bool b){
 while (binaryItem->next != NULL) {
  binaryItem = binaryItem->next;
 }
 struct BinaryItem* newBinaryItem = malloc(sizeof(struct BinaryItem));
 binaryItem->next = newBinaryItem;
 newBinaryItem->b = b;
 newBinaryItem->next = NULL;
}`

Comment: And, yes, this is my little personal project to learn C, so thanks again for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Arman, the reason that code works is because it's not designed to start a new list, just to add to an already existing one - that will work fine since the things you are changing are within the list - you have their addresses. That's the problem with your original code, the thing you're changing is a local variable inside the function, _not_ the original one you passed in.

Comment: Alright, I think I understood now. In all circumstances except NULL I am modifying the actual data, whereas in the NULL scenario what I wish to modify is actually the _pointer_ itself. Hence the need for a pointer to the pointer, in order to make that feasible. Walrii's example below helped too. Thanks, paxdiablo—although I don't have it solved quite yet I am getting there!

Comment: @Arman, by Thor's mighty hammer, I think you have it :-) Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in the root of your list by value, so the actual root is never modified.  pass in the &root instead so that it can be modified.

```
struct PathItem *root = NULL;

void addPathItemAtEnd(struct PathItem **pRoot, struct BinaryItem * binaryItem) {
    // advance pRoot so that either it points to the original root or it
    // points at the next field of the last item
    while (*pRoot)
        pRoot = &(*pRoot)->next;
    // add the new item
    struct PathItem *p = malloc(sizeof(struct PathItem));
    // TODO check p!= NULL
    p->next = NULL;
    p->binaryItem = binaryItem;
    *pRoot = p;
}
```

Called like

```
addPathItemAtEnd(&root, blah);
```

Comment: Thanks walrii, still don't quite have it working yet, but your example helped me understand the problem and see how to address it.